# loop through $_POST variables with similar names

Tags: php, string

I have several $_POST variables, they are

```
$_POST['item_number1']
$_POST['item_number2']
```

and so on

I need to write a loop tha displays the values of all the variables (I don't know how many there are). What would be a simplest way to go about it? Also what would be the simplest way if I do know how many variables I have?

Comment: Are you getting these values from a form? Could use a form array style submit by setting the form element to: name='item_number[]' style so that you can just loop through that one array in the $_POST variables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will echo all POST parameters whose names start with `item_number`:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos($k, 'item_number') === 0) {
        echo "$k = $v";
    }
}
```

PHP Manual: [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 4):

If you know how many do you have:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $num_of_vars; $i++)
    echo $_POST['item_number'.$i]."<br />";
```

**UPDATE:**
If not:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $pos = strpos($k, "item_number");
    if($pos === 0)
        echo $v."<br />";
}
```

Gets all POST variables that are like "item_number"

**UPD 2**: Changed "==" to "===" because of  piotrekkr's comment. Thanks

Comment: You should use `if($pos === 0)` because `strpos()` returns `0` when needle is on the begining of string and `false` when needle is not found.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    if(strpos($k, 'item_number') === 0)
    {
        echo "$k = $v";
    }
}
```

In the above example, **$k** will be the array key and **$v** would be the value.

Comment: there are other $_POST variables too, I just need the ones that start with "item_number"

Comment: I think whet @Natalia wanted is that `item_number` is at the begining of key, so there should be `strpos($k, 'item_number') === 0`

Answer (score 1):

if you know the number of variables:

```
<?php
$n = 25; // the max number of variables
$name = 'item_number';  // the name of variables
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
  if (isset($_POST[$name . $i])) {
    echo $_POST[$name . $i];
  }
}
```

if you don't know the number:

```
<?php
$name = 'item_number';
foreach ($_POST as $key) {
  if (strpos($key, $name) > 0) {
    echo $_POST[$key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you must stick with those variable names like item_numberX

```
foreach (array_intersect_key($_POST, preg_grep('#^item_number\d+$#D', array_keys($_POST))) as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k $v \n";
}
```

or

```
foreach (new RegexIterator(new ArrayIterator($_POST), '#^a\d+$#D', null, RegexIterator::USE_KEY) as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k $v \n";
}
```

Better to use php's [input variable array feature](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays), if you can control the input names.

```
<input name="item_number[]">
<input name="item_number[]">
<input name="item_number[]">
```

then php processes it into an array for you.

```
print_r($_POST['item_number']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(preg_match("#item_number([0-9]+)#si", $k, $keyMatch)) {
        $number = $keyMatch[1];

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
while (list($key,$value) = each($_POST))
   ${$key} = trim($value);
```