# proper structure for array of form field names for both jquery validation and php processing

Tags: php, jquery, html

The simplified form in the html code below contains a number of repetitive form fields which must be both validated by means of some jquery validate code and processed by means of some php code...I have set up the form field below to facilitate the php processing, but then again get stuck with writing the proper jquery validate code as the 'name' tags are supposed to be unique. If I'd make the name tags unique I think the php coding becomes more complex.

Just wondering what a proper structure of repetitive form fields would be which facilitates both the jquery validation coding and php coding?

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check0" name="productselection[]" value="productselected0">
<input id="nrofparts0" type="text" name="nrofparts[]">

<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="productselection[]" value="productselected1">
<input id="nrofparts1" type="text" name="nrofparts[]">

<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="productselection[]" value="productselected2">
<input id="nrofparts2" type="text" name="nrofparts[]">
```

Comment: try making the name like the id.
Example:
<input type="checkbox" id="check0" name="productselection0" value="productselected0">
<input id="nrofparts0" type="text" name="nrofparts0">

Comment: thnx for your suggestion. I thought about that idea too, but as indicated, how to write the php code for for example nrofparts0, nrofparts1, nrofparts3, etc. in a simple way? (with an array nrofparts[] that's easy)

Comment: UPDATE: I found a solution on this site with respect to my question in my previous comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567847/loop-through-post-variables-with-similar-names. For the validation code I guess I this need to add rules for each item (nrofparts0, nrofparts1, etc.) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres one way you can do it:

HTML

```
    <form id="theForm" method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checky[0]" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checky[1]" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checky[2]" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

I add a key to the array because it makes it easier to determine which checkboxes were clicked. you wont get anything for an unclicked one.  that can make it confusing

jquery:

```
$('#theForm input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    // if($(this))... some validation
});
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST['checky'])){
    foreach($_POST['checky'] as $key => $val){
        echo $key.'  '.$val;  // this will give you the key of the checkbox, and the value 
    }
}
```

you could also have a hidden input that counts the checkboxes.  That way when you loop, you can use it to set the empty checkboxes in your php code.

hope this helps!

Comment: thnx for the suggestion(!), will try that