# PHP - Looping $_POST in PHP Query

Tags: php, loops, post

First im a student. Im just trying to make a looping in $_POST php statements like this

```
if ($_POST) { //Get value of Latitude, Longitude, Radius from site.php to calculate in Query above
    include('config/dbconnect.php'); //Database connection
    $lat = array();
    $lon = array();
    $rad = array();
    $stmt = array();
    $sql = array();

    $lat1 = $_POST['lat1']; //Get value of Latitude 1
    $lon1 = $_POST['lon1']; //Get value of Longitude 1
    $rad1 = $_POST['rad1']; //Get value of Radius 1
    $endrow = $_POST['endrow'];

    for ($i = 2; $i <= $endrow; $i++) {
        $lat[$i] = $_POST['lat'.$i]; //Get value of Latitude n
        $lon[$i] = $_POST['lon'.$i]; //Get value of Longitude n
        $rad[$i] = $_POST['rad'.$i]; //Get value of Radius n
    }

    //Haversine Formula and view only match Site CI and d2g_trx CI
    $sql = "SELECT site.*,d2g_trx.*, 
       ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat1) ) 
                      * cos( radians( site.latitude ) ) 
                      * cos( radians( site.longitude ) - radians($lon1) ) 
                    +   sin( radians($lat1) ) 
                      * sin( radians( site.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
       FROM site 
       INNER JOIN d2g_trx ON site.ci = d2g_trx.CI 
       HAVING distance <=$rad1 
       ORDER BY distance 
       LIMIT 0 , 50"; 

    $stmt = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(); // Input 1

    for ($j = 2; $j <= $endrow; $j++) {
        //Haversine Formula and view only match Site CI and d2g_trx CI
        $sql[$j] = "SELECT site.*,d2g_trx.*, 
           ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat[$j]) ) 
                          * cos( radians( site.latitude ) ) 
                          * cos( radians( site.longitude ) - radians($lon[$j]) ) 
                        +   sin( radians($lat[$j]) ) 
                          * sin( radians( site.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
           FROM site 
           INNER JOIN d2g_trx ON site.ci = d2g_trx.CI 
           HAVING distance <=$rad[$j] 
           ORDER BY distance 
           LIMIT 0 , 50"; 
        $stmt[$j] = $dbh->query($sql[$j])->fetchAll(); //Input n
    }
}
```

I got error like this

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in
>   F:\XAMPP\htdocs\kp\getsite.php on line 28

Anyway, line 28 is this one

```
$stmt[$j]= $dbh->query($sql[$j])->fetchAll(); //Input n
```

Sorry, my is english is really bad :(

Any idea how to fix this sir ?

Thanks before

Comment: Show your dbconnect.php file

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  You shouldn't build queries by concatenating strings, especially not when user input is involved because user input cannot be trusted.  Use MySQLI/PDO's prepared statement functionality instead.

Comment: i think it look like in this question : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567847/loop-through-post-variables-with-similar-names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567847/loop-through-post-variables-with-similar-names)

Comment: I'm not sure, if it is only due to formatting question here on SO, but you dont have there closing parenthesis on `if ( $_POST )` statement.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with the loop over `$_POST`. The line you are getting the error on is where you are talking to the database. The steps to debug this are to examine `$sql[$j]`, and the result of `$dbh->query(...)`, and to look up how to view errors on your DB connector.

Comment: Thanks before, but im not sure my dbconnect.php is the problem. Because when i test it to access db on different page, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it could be like this

```
if( $_POST ){ //Get value of Latitude, Longitude, Radius from site.php to calculate in Query above
include('config/dbconnect.php'); //Database connection
$tempsss = array("");
$lat = array("");
$lon = array("");
$rad = array("");  

$j=1;
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos($k, 'lat') === 0) {
        $lat[$j] =$v; //Get value of Latitude
        $j++;
    }
};
$z=1;
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos($k, 'lon') === 0) {
        $lon[$z] =$v; //Get value of Latitude
        $z++;
    }
};
$h=1;
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos($k, 'rad') === 0) {
        $rad[$h] =$v; //Get value of Latitude
        $h++;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can do this:

```
$dbh->query($sql[$j])->fetchAll();
```

doesn't mean you should. At least for testing purposes you should really look at the return values (I assume you use PDO):

```
$result = $db->query($sql[$j]);
if($result === false) {
    print_r($db->errorInfo());
    exit;
}
$stmt[$j] = $result->fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks before, i got this sir " Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'S' at line 1 )"

Comment: the error doesn't match your query, please update your code above to show the actual code (even though your code formatting is horrible), did you add a space or something after the S of SELECT?