# Loop $_POST variable with different name

Tags: php

How loop $_POST variable with different name, this the output from print_r :

the post :

```
$_POST['post_access_1'];
$_POST['post_access_2'];
$_POST['post_access_3'];
$_POST['post_access_4'];

Array
(
    [post_access_1] = Array
        (
            [0] = 1
            [1] = 6
        )

    [post_access_2] = Array
        (
            [0] = 1
            [1] = 4
        )

    [post_access_3] = Array
        (
            [0] = 2
            [1] = 5
            [2] = 6
        )

    [post_access_4] = Array
        (
            [0] = 2
            [1] = 5
        )
)
```

where

```
    1 => 1,6
    2 => 1,4
    3 => 2,5,6
    4 => 2,5
```

i have search and see but no with diferent name.

thankyou

Comment: And what is question here? what you want? what you tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: foreach($_POST as $postKey => $postValue){
    echo "$postKey = $postValue \n";
}

Comment: use var_export() on your array and update your question we can help you

Comment: @Anant MyQuestion is "How loop variable with different name"? i have tried to follow and mofidied http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567847/loop-through-post-variables-with-similar-names but not get the result.

Comment: @febriit  do you want something like this:-https://eval.in/615372

Comment: Or may be like this:-https://eval.in/615376

Comment: @Anant yes you right but i can't give 1+..thankyou

Comment: @Anant sory i late to see your answer..i can't unmarked. but you right may be any other user can give you +1

Comment: @febriit  you can unmarked answer any time and gave mark to better one. but no need to do it if you get your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `foreach` loop on the POST variable like this.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    if (is_array($value)){
        echo $key ." Is an array in post.";
        foreach ($value as $k => $v){
            echo $k." is the index and ".$v." is the value in the array.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `foreach`.

```
foreach ($array as $foo)
{
// do something with $foo
}
```

If you need access to the keys / subarray names as well:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
// do something with $k and or $v
}
```

Comment: This isn't really correct, because $_POST is associative in his case, Use `$key => $value`

Comment: He did not indicate that he needs to preserve or use the keys in his example output.